# Single Source Shortest Path with constraint lower bound of minimum cost

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

Problem description:

Given a graph G in adjacencyMatrix and adjacencyList, inside which there is a source vertex s and a destination vertex d. Find the shortest path from s to d, with a constraint. The constraint is that the shortest path cost c has a lower bound, i.e., the cost c must be greater than an assigned lower bound N but is the smallest in all the costs of possible paths that are greater or equal N.

I understand with this constraint conventional SSSP algorithm like Bellman ford cannot work correctly. How shall I find a most efficient algorithm for this problem?

Comment: do you allow cycle in the answer?

Comment: I know if there isnt cycle this problem will be NP hard, since when the graph is unweighted and lower bound equals |V|-1, then it is equivalent to finding a Hamiltonian path. I guess a complete search would suffice. As a result, I am more interested in the solution where cycles are permitted.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you wanted a walk, since path cannot have cycles.

Unfortunately, the problem can be easily modeled as change-making problem, which is NPC too.

Change-making problem: Given N types of coins of c_i value each, is it possible that number X can be changed with those N coins?

Modelling: Assume all c_i's are even (double all c_i, and also X, if not). Create N + 2 vertices, which the i-th vertex represents the i-th coin for 1 <= i <= N. Also, the (N+1) and (N+2)-th vertices have edge to all coins with cost (c_i / 2). The problem is then equivalent to finding a shortest path of cost at least X, which is NPC. The reduction should be obvious, but if further explanations are needed I can edit my answer.